# NullPointerException whe reading audio from JAR

Tags: java, inputstream

I tried to make a runnable JAR, but for some reason I couldn't get my game to play. I did some research and ran it through my command prompt to try to find the error and I got this below. So obviously I know the issue I just need to fix it. I am new to programming so not quite sure what this is telling me.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at builder.AudioPlayer.playMenuSound(AudioPlayer.java:20)
        at builder.Game.<init>(Game.java:56)
        at builder.Game.main(Game.java:61)
```

```
package builder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class AudioPlayer {

    private static Clip play;

    public static void playMenuSound()
    {
        try {
            //AudioInputStream menuSound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("src/res/introSong.wav")); //Take in audio from res folder
            AudioInputStream menuSound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioPlayer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/introSong.wav"));
            play = AudioSystem.getClip(); //
            play.open(menuSound); //Play the sound
            FloatControl volume = (FloatControl) play.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN); //Get control of volume
            volume.setValue(1.0f); //0.0 - 1.0 volume
            play.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); //Loop once clip is over
        }catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void playGameSound()
    {
        try {
            //AudioInputStream gameSound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("src/res/inGame.wav")); //Take in audio from res folder
            AudioInputStream gameSound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioPlayer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/inGame.wav"));
            play = AudioSystem.getClip(); //
            play.open(gameSound); //Play the sound
            FloatControl volume = (FloatControl) play.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN); //Get control of volume
            volume.setValue(0.5f); //0.0 - 1.0 volume
            play.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); //Loop once clip is over
        }catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void stopMusic()
    {
        play.close(); //Stop music
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `introSong.wav` in your JAR?

Comment: The resource "introSong.wav" is not available in your project/JAR.

Comment: @dan1st I am new to programming and this is my first time exporting. I just hit extract libraries into JAR. So maybe?

Comment: @Progman So if I use the lines I comment out, it works in eclipse just not JAR. However I was told I can't use File in this situation for some reason? So I tried this way, but I get the error above.

Comment: What IDE do you use? Where is the sound file located? Can you show it (directory structure)?

Comment: @dan1st Eclipse. src > builder, enemies, res -> res has inGame.wav and introSong.wav

Comment: Rename the `.jar` file to a `.zip` file. Is the wav file in the root of the zip file?

Comment: What about using `res/inGame.wav` instead of `inGame.wav`?

Comment: @dan1st yes it is in the .zip

Comment: Is it in the root of the zip or in a subdirectory `res`?

Comment: @dan1st it is in subdirectory, I ran in eclipse with changes you said and no error. I will try exporting now.

Comment: `java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
        at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.SunFileReader.getAudioFileFormat(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.WaveExtensibleFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
   …` When I ran in command prompt ^

Comment: Followed by this after I hit play in my game. `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at builder.AudioPlayer.stopMusic(AudioPlayer.java:48)
        at builder.Menu.mousePressed(Menu.java:58)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sound file `inGame.wav` is located in a directory `res` inside your source directory.

When you export it, the sources will be compiled and copied to the JAR.

This results in the sound file being in a subdirectory `res` inside the JAR.

You try to read the file `inGame.wav` but you have to read `res/inGame.wav` instead.

The second problem is that the system cannot set markers on the `InputStream`. This can be solved by changing `getResourceAsStream` to `getResource()`.

```
AudioInputStream menuSound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioPlayer.class.getClassLoader().getResource("res/inGame.wav"));
```

Comment: I edited above. I did that change and it worked in eclipse. But I get exception I post in comments above

Comment: What abour changing `getResourceAsStream` to `getResource()`?